# How to do this image zooming trick in a browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, user-interface, image-manipulation, zooming

I would like to do the following trick in a browser:

Create three image files of different size (small, medium, large) from one picture.

- First, display the small image in a
  browser.
- When a user zooms in the small image
  *replace* it with the medium one.
  Now the user can scroll it within the
  window up and down, left and right.
- When a user zooms out the small image
  replace it with the small one, etc.

I would prefer JavaScript (Flash is the second option). What tool would you recommend ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search turns up:

http://www.intenseblog.com/design/8-amazing-javascript-image-zoom-scripts.html

and:

http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-zoom-scripts/

Several of these libraries appear to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

http://www.netzgesta.de/shiftzoom/

This might be for image data that is much larger than you are interested in.